# The mean random walk on a spherical lattice excursion length

Tags: probability, group-actions, random-walk, symmetry

In [this Jane Street puzzle](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/andys-morning-stroll-index/), [its solution](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/andys-morning-stroll-solution/) says the mean stroll length is $20$. The arugment is kind of plausible but not clear. I would like to see a rigorous proof utilizing the symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any irreducible finite Markov chain,
the expected return time to the initial state $x_0$  is $1/\pi(x_0)$,
where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution. See [1] or [2], Prop. 1.19 page 13.
For simple random walk on a regular graph, the stationary distribution is uniform (see example 1.21 in [2]) so  $1/\pi(x_0)$ is just the number of states of the chain, i.e. the number of white hexagons on the soccer ball.

[1]   James Robert Norris. Markov chains.   Cambridge university press, 1998.

[2] https://www.yuval-peres-books.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times/
https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf

Comment: Accepted this answer and +1. I like this answer derived from your book. However, this answer hinges on realizing the relation between the expected return time to the initial state and the stationary distribution. 1) Is there a natural way to see this as obviously true? 2) Is there a simple way to compute this without resorting to the stationary distribution?